# PHP - While and echo on HTML Div

Tags: php, html

I have this problem :

I have 2 php files > index.php and control.php.

Inside control.php are a variable called `"$ControlNumber"`, this has the default value on 10 and a variable called `"$Name"`

Inside index.php I have a while with a condition `($ControlNumber < 10)` and each time this it's executed , `$ControlNumber` its increased by 1.

The end of the code  i made a div with the name of `"$Name"`, but  this doesn't work.

I execute the code by this way with a href link :

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run_func'] == 'yes') { 
include "control.php";
$ControlNumber--;
} else { 
echo '<a href="?run_func=yes">Press here 2 add a player</a>'; 
} 
?>
```

Code inside the while :

```
<?php
include "control.php";
while($ControlNumber < 10) {
$ControlNumber++;
echo '<div id="Linea1" style="background-color#751313; color:white; font-       size:150%;";>' . $Name .'</div>';
$Name = "Used";
}
?>
```

Code of "Control.php"

```
<?php
$ControlNumber;
$ControlNumber = 10;
$Name = "John";
?>
```

I try a lot of different options when writing this code , but the `"Text/Echo"` doesn't work or appears.

Comment: what do you really want to do my friend?

Comment: It'd be good if you provided an idea of what you expect as a result

Answer (score 0):

this does not work because of the var `$ControlNumber = 10`
and the `while` condition only run if this var less than 10 
try to declare this var `$controlNumber = 0` may be this work ^^

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of **$ControlNumber** is 10. After that your condition saying that

```
while( $ControlNumber < 10){
    // code here
}
```

That means-

```
while( 10 < 10){
    // code here
}
```

Which is always false. Change your initial value or the limit to get the result you want.